# Process Engine Dispatcher exception while transferring the workflow

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-process-engine

When a workflow is being transferred the PE error occurred. I am using custom components other than CE_Operations in workflow.

ERROR STACK:

```
[FATAL 09 Apr 2014 15:25:21] Dispatcher got exception while doing query at April 9, 2014 3:25:21 PM GMT+05:30.  Cause=[FNRPE2131090092E]The work space time stamp is stale

The work space has been updated by transfer, so the client workstation needs to load new workspaces and a new time stamp.
at filenet.pe.peorb.client.ORBUtility.mapServerException(ORBUtility.java:529)
at filenet.pe.peorb.client.ORBSession.executeRPC(ORBSession.java:1266)
at filenet.pe.peorb.client.ORBSession.fetch(ORBSession.java:2112)
at filenet.vw.api.VWQuery.fetch(VWQuery.java:653)
at filenet.vw.api.VWQueueQuery.dofetch(VWQueueQuery.java:429)
at filenet.vw.api.VWQuery.hasNext(VWQuery.java:768)
at filenet.vw.api.VWQueueQuery.hasNext(VWQueueQuery.java:461)
at filenet.vw.integrator.base.VWAdaptorControlEx$WorkflowDispatcher.run(VWAdaptorControlEx.java:359)

Root Cause:
[FNRPE2131090092E]The work space time stamp is stale
 The work space has been updated by transfer, so the client workstation needs to load new workspaces and a new time stamp.

at filenet.jpe.server.common.IVWRuntimeServer.checkTimeStamps(IVWRuntimeServer.java:4754)
at filenet.jpe.server.common.IVWRuntimeServer.InitSession(IVWRuntimeServer.java:4064)
at filenet.jpe.rpc.orb.OrbRPC.<init>(OrbRPC.java:696)
at filenet.jpe.rpc.orb.ORBPERPC.orb_rpc_fetchQuery(ORBPERPC.java:911)
at filenet.pe.peorb.FileNet_PERPC.PERPCPOA._invoke(PERPCPOA.java:697)
at com.ibm.CORBA.poa.POAServerDelegate.dispatchToServant(POAServerDelegate.java:402)
at com.ibm.CORBA.poa.POAServerDelegate.internalDispatch(POAServerDelegate.java:334)
at com.ibm.CORBA.poa.POAServerDelegate.dispatch(POAServerDelegate.java:256)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:518)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1574)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.respondTo(Connection.java:2880)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2753)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:63)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:202)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
```

How can I resolve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration of your connection point

to make sure it work : 
run (install dir)FileNet\AE\Router\routercmd.bat
click on connection point, in the right panel under general tab clic on buton "display work queue"
    -> this action try a connection from AE to PE, to retrieve names of your work queues. 
    if it work your connection point should be working 
    if not, see vwtaskman.log under (install dir)FileNet\AE\Router\ for more details